# CSS hover image replacement

Tags: css, image, hover, sprite, replace

Using a method I've done before but having issues. Not sure if it's a sprite or what.. Basically you have two versions of an image saved into one file with them stacked on top of each other and use CSS to adjust the margins when hovering. Here's an example of it working successfully: http://minimalpluscreative.com

Trying to do the same thing here, but running into issues with overflow:hidden; not working. Instead, the the full (double) image is shown. Here's what it looks like: http://cl.ly/023p1I1D1W0W3a1T1q1R It should be just the top half of the image with overflow:hidden; preventing the other half from showing.

Help? Some kind of syntax error I'm sure...

HTML:

```
    <div id="work" class="sub">
        <h3>MUSIC VIDEOS</h3>
        <img id="show_fire" class="thumbnail sprite" src="images/daniel_gomes_soundoffire_sprite.png" />
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.sprite {
        width:140px; 
        height:61px; 
        overflow:hidden;
}
.sprite:hover {
        margin-top:-61px;
}
```

Comment: Its usually easier to implement sprites using background image positions.  See http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/ for a good example.

Comment: @Steve Jorgensen - Considered using css backgrounds, but these are simple image thumbnails and I thought it was unncecessary work. If the markup won't work with <img> then I'll make them <div>s with backgrounds. Theoretically though, there isn't a reason why this shouldn't work. This is the same markup as the example http://minimalpluscreative.com

Comment: Can you provide a link to the sprite image?

Comment: I would think that manipulating the margin of an image tag is at least as much more work as changing the position background image.  At the very least, there are far more examples of how to do it with background image position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen this done before except with background images, but I don't see why not… it just seems like you need a lot of extra css, and extra html to get it to work as opposed to a background image.

As was said earlier, it's hard to see the problem without seeing your actual code in context, but based on what I see, there could be a few potential things wrong:

You need to wrap the image in a containing element, and assign the width, height and overflow to that.  Hidden overflow will hide what's outside of the boundaries that div *contains*. The image element *is* the image, it doesn't contain the image, so setting it to overflow:hidden isn't going to hide andything, and assigning it a width will just resize it, not "crop" it (which is the effect you're going for).  So you'd need something like:

```
<div id="work" class="sub">
    <h3>MUSIC VIDEOS</h3>
    <a class="sprite" href="#">
        <img id="show_fire" class="thumbnail" src="images/daniel_gomes_soundoffire_sprite.png" />
    </a>
</div>
```

with this css:

```
.sprite {
    width:140px; 
    height:61px; 
    overflow:hidden;
}
.sprite img {
    margin-top: 0;
}
.sprite:hover img {
    margin-top: -61px;
}
```

I suggest you use 'a' as the containing element, as not all browsers will recognize the hover pseudo-class on tags other than anchor tags.

I know you think using an image instead of a background image is simpler, but using background images, you can accomplish all this with only one element and less css.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Already started changing the method. Thank you for the in depth answer.

Comment: Small and quick other thought regarding using anchors to ensure that the hover pseudo-class is recognized: What markup do you suggest? I figured that a <div> with the associated background image and .sprite:hover class would work (and does), but seems to conflict with your advice. These are technically links, but only to trigger JavaScript functions.

Comment: You only need to worry about it if you're concerned about having full functionality down to IE6.  IE6 doesn't not recognize ":hover" on anything except anchor tags.  I do believe all other relevant browsers will.  Semantically, the div is probably a better choice, as this does not really serve the function of an anchor.  But using the a tag is just a quick and dirty way to keep the most cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: Fantastic, I'm happily unconcerned with IE6. Thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 1):

In the example site you refer to, the overflow:hidden property is set on the outer 'div#a'
'div#work' in your code should have it's overflow set to hidden.

Thus when you change the margin on your image it will move within the frame of your outer div.

Additionally I had to add a tag name to the hover declaration.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#work{  
        position:relative;
        overflow:hidden;
        width:140px;
        height:61px; 
}
div.sprite {
        margin-top:0;    
}

div.sprite:hover {
        margin-top:-61px;
}
/* instead of an image */
.sprite div{
 height:61px;
}
.red {background:red}
.blue {background:blue}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="work">
 <div class="sprite">
  <div class="red">a</div>
  <div class="blue">b</div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I see what you're saying. God, I'm sloppy. I think I'll end up using the background-image property because there are several images within the #work div. Thank you for pointing out the error.